# Comparing a two-hand weapon with two one-hand weapons in the inventory

Tags: diablo-iii

When comparing a two-handed weapon in your inventory with two one-handed weapons like this:

[image]

Are the stats shown taking both one-handers into account, or just the displayed one? Notice that there's no option to compare with the off-hand using the alt-key, here.

Comment: just point that your 2h is **lv17** while your 1h is **lv25**...

Comment: Thanks, I must've missed that. I will not equip it now.

Comment: Dual-wield questions have already been answered, try using search function :o

Comment: @Domocus you can click and flag this question with the link of the possible duplicated. You even won some badges doing this.

Comment: It's not entirely a duplicate, however. I don't think there's a question that focuses on comparisons between dual wield and 2h, he just needs to edit the questions a little.

Comment: @Domocus You can edit his question without any trouble, *but without 2000+ rep, you'll need a approve.*

Comment: First of all, this must be a bad question. 99 views, 5 comments and one upvote :P Second: What do you suggest as a new title? Add "in the inventory" to the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does indeed take both weapons into account. This can be tested by simply removing one of the two one-handers and then comparing the two-handed weapon with the remaining one-hander. The difference in stats shown will be different.